# HTML and PHP 5 States Per Row

Tags: php, html, count, rows

I'm wanting to have a list of states and the cities under it.  I want 5 states per row with the cities that have records under it, then I want it to start a new row.  I started trying to figure it out and I've been going for hours and my brain hurts.  Can anyone help?

Here's what I have right now:

```
$lookup = "SELECT state, city, count(city) as num FROM needs WHERE country IS NULL AND 

status='posted' GROUP BY state, city ORDER BY state, city";
if ($result = mysql_query($lookup)) {
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        echo "<table>";
        $i = 1;
        $cols = 3;
        $prev = '';
        while ($frows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $fcity = $frows['city'];
                $fstate = $frows['state'];
                $fcitycount = $frows['num'];  // num is holding your count by city

if ($fstate != $prev) {
echo "<tr><td><h2>$fstate</h2></td>";
$prev = $fstate;
}


echo "<tr><td><a href='browseresults.php?city=$fcity&state=$fstate'>$fcity, $fstate ($fcitycount)</a></td></tr>";


}
echo "</table>";
}
```

***EDIT:***

It should look like this:

```
Arkansas               Tennessee           Missouri
Searcy, AR (1)         Bartlett, TN (1)    St. Louis, MO (4)
Little Rock, AR (4)    Memphis, TN (3)     Perry, MO (3)
Benton, AR (2)                             Branson, MO (1)
                                           Shell, MO (2)
```

Except it will be done 5 times instead of 3

***EDIT 2:***

Here's the code I tried but it's still not working :-/

```
$lookup = "SELECT state, city, count(city) as num FROM needs WHERE country IS NULL AND status='posted' GROUP BY state, city ORDER BY state, city";
if ($result = mysql_query($lookup)) {
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        echo "<table><td>";
        $i = 1;
        $j = 1;
        $cols = 5;
        $prev = '';
        while ($frows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $fcity = $frows['city'];
                $fstate = $frows['state'];
                $fcitycount = $frows['num'];  // num is holding your count by city

if ($fstate != $prev) {
echo "<tr><h2>$fstate</h2></tr>";
$prev = $fstate;
}


echo "<tr><a href='browseresults.php?city=$fcity&state=$fstate'>$fcity, $fstate ($fcitycount)</a><br></tr>";

if ($fstate != $prev) {
echo "</td><td>";
}


}
echo "</td></table>";
}
```

Comment: count how many states you've output, once you reach a multiple of 5, you start a new row. That's not going to work with your code, however, since you're starting a new row on every iteration anyways.

Comment: I'm confused on the HTML of how to do that in tables.  Everything I try doesn't work :-/

Comment: Can you post a sample of the desired html output?

Comment: build a mockup in html by hand. that'll make it easier to see how php should generate that for you.

Comment: I edited the post to show how I see it looking.

Comment: My problem is that I have to have the php do the state then list all the cities.  I can't have it list 5 cities, then the cities under it.  Know what I mean?

Comment: I edited the post again to show something I tried but didn't work...I kind of feel like I'm getting close but then again I'm new to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, based off your current code attempt. The state and all of its cities are within the same cell.

```
echo "<table>";
     $i = 1;
     $cols = 3;  // of cells per row
     $prev = '';
echo "<tr>";   // start the first row  
while ($frows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $fcity = $frows['city'];
        $fstate = $frows['state'];
        $fcitycount = $frows['num'];  // num is holding your count by city

        if ($fstate != $prev) {

            if($i>$cols){  // check if we have reached our # of $cols
                echo "</td></tr><tr>";  // end cell/row and start new row
                $i=1; //reset counter
            }
            elseif ($prev != '') {  // if not the first cell/state
                echo "</td>";  // end cell before starting new cell/state
            }
            echo "<td><h2>$fstate</h2>";
            $prev = $fstate;
            $i++;
        }


        echo "<a href='browseresults.php?city=$fcity&state=$fstate'>$fcity, $fstate ($fcitycount)</a><br />";


}
echo "</td></tr>"; //end the last cell/row
echo "</table>";
```

By changing `$cols` value (ie `$cols=5`, you can change the number of cells per row.
See an example of this in a phpfiddle - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pkg-90i

this creates a table like this-
[image: example snapshot]